How to determine if my control system is following the most controllable direction?
I have a linear discrete time control system $x (t) = A.x(t-1) + B.u$. I computed the controllability matrix ($C$) of this system and did singular vector decomposition (SVD) of the $C$ matrix, $USV_h = svd(C)$. And deduced that the columns of the $V$ vector are ordered as the most controllable directions.
Now to determine whether my system is following/aligned with the most controllable directions I calculated cosine similarity between the column vectors of the $V$ and the  $x$ vector at time $t$.
Is this the right approach to interpret whether my existing system is aligned with the most controllable directions? If not what is wrong with my approach and how to make it right?
Thanks!

First of all I have never heard of a "most controllable direction"? But unless that direction vector is not eigenvector of $A$ I think you can create examples that the solutions diverge from that direction.

This is a reference (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNHx62HbKNA) about what people mean when they say "most controllable".
